# Galaxy Note 5 suddenly stopped booting up and in recovery mode has dm-verity and failed to mount errors?

Tags: boot-loop, system-error, samsung-galaxy-note-5

All of sudden when I was trying to use my note 5 (unroot), I noticed that it was powered off and I couldn't power it on with power button. Can you please tell me if there is a way I can recover data on my phone without losing them? I also have Google Authenticator which is connected to many accounts online, If I lose data I will lose everything! Here is what I tried so far:

First thing I did was a soft reset ( power button + volume down) and the mobile turned on but unfortunately it kept looping on the Samsung logo screen. Then, I tried to go to recovery mode (power button + home button + volume up) and from there I tried "reboot system now", "wiping cache partition (which I hope it doesn't remove any data?)" and "Run graphics test: which failed with error no command and then wiping cached data" all of them without success. One thing I noticed in the bottom section of recovery mode there are these errors:

```
ODIN MODE
DOWNLOAD SPEED: FAST
PRODUCT NAME: SM-N920C
CA_ TYPE: CA_2
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
FRP LOCK: ON
Secure Download : Enabled
KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0 (0x0000)
RP SWREV: B:5 K:0 S:1

Android Recovery
samsung/nobleltejv/noblelte
7.0/NRD90M/N920CXXS5CRH1
user/release-keys

No Support SINGLE-SKU
Supported API: 3
dm-verity error...
E: failed to mount /system (Invalid argument)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133355/discussion-on-question-by-haloking-galaxy-note-5-suddenly-stopped-booting-up-and).

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. System automatically deletes a chat room when it meets some [criteria for deletion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention). I have undeleted the chat room now. You should be able to access the chat room now. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to flash all partition images (except `userdata.img`) via heimdall command line

```
heimdall flash --BOOTLOADER sboot.bin --CM cm.bin --PARAM param.bin --BOOT boot.img --RECOVERY recovery.img --RADIO modem.bin --SYSTEM system.img --CACHE cache.img --HIDDEN hidden.img
```

---

The above example command is created from partition list. This is how you get pit file

- install [heimdall](https://www.glassechidna.com.au/heimdall), [python](https://www.python.org) and [samloader](https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy)
- download and decrypt stock ROM for your region code

  ```
  C:\Android\samloader>samloader -m SM-N920C -r AFR checkupdate
  N920CXXS5CRH1/N920COJV4CRB3/N920CXXU5CRH1/N920CXXS5CRH1

  C:\Android\samloader>samloader -m SM-N920C -r AFR download -v N920CXXS5CRH1/N920COJV4CRB3/N920CXXU5CRH1/N920CXXS5CRH1 -O .
  downloading SM-N920C_1_20180820163853_vvggswhd8u_fac.zip.enc4
  [################################] 38453/38453 - 00:06:20

  C:\Android\samloader>samloader -m SM-N920C -r AFR decrypt -v N920CXXS5CRH1/N920COJV4CRB3/N920CXXU5CRH1/N920CXXS5CRH1 -V 4 -i SM-N920C_1_20180820163853_vvggswhd8u_fac.zip.enc4 -o SM-N920C_1_20180820163853_vvggswhd8u_fac.zip
  [################################] 615247/615247 - 00:01:21
  ```
- unpack files from zip

  ```
  C:\Android\samloader>7z l SM-N920C_1_20180820163853_vvggswhd8u_fac.zip

  7-Zip 18.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-01-28

  Scanning the drive for archives:
  1 file, 2520047837 bytes (2404 MiB)

  Listing archive: SM-N920C_1_20180820163853_vvggswhd8u_fac.zip

  --
  Path = SM-N920C_1_20180820163853_vvggswhd8u_fac.zip
  Type = zip
  Physical Size = 2520047837
  64-bit = +
  Characteristics = Zip64

     Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
  ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
  2018-08-20 16:39:50 .....      5058737      1491256  BL_N920CXXS5CRH1_CL11762721_QB19211222_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
  2018-08-20 16:39:50 .....   4797583545   2248597336  AP_N920CXXS5CRH1_CL11762721_QB19211222_REV00_user_low_ship_meta.tar.md5
  2018-08-20 16:44:16 .....     38092989     38093065  CP_N920CXXU5CRH1_CP10334463_CL11762721_QB19211222_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
  2018-08-20 16:44:18 .....    273756344    231865000  CSC_OJV_N920COJV4CRB3_CL11762721_QB16863364_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
  ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
  2018-08-20 16:44:18         5114491615   2520046657  4 files
  ```
- extract pit from CSC file

  ```
  CSC_OJV_N920COJV4CRB3_CL11762721_QB16863364_REV00_user_low_ship.tar.md5
  ```
- inspect `NOBLELTE_EUR_OPEN_HIDDEN150M.pit` pit file with [PIT Magic](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916936) or [PIT Viewer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2953072)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133354/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-galaxy-note-5-suddenly-stopped-booting-up-and-in).