# Odin is failing at flashing Samsung Galaxy Note 5

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-note-5

I have SM-N920C which is stuck at [blank screen with background color of download page or download mode page screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hJrE.jpg) I tried restoring and flashing it with Odin (two different versions v3.13.1 and v3.12) but it kept failing, I tried different version of the original firmware ([the four files: AP,BL,CP, and CSC version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYwhz.jpg)+ one big file (...._HOME.tar.md5.rar)) different computers and cables. Still fails. I also tried flashing with [hiemdall](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244468/) that also failed. Any idea what is going on and what can I do? I don't want to lose my data, please help!

Comment: `FRP LOCK: ON`?

Comment: Yes, right now it's on. Before was off, it goes on and off with flashing attempts. Also, the "CURRENT BINARY" now is at "Samsung Official" yesterday was "Custom" before flashing it.  And "SYSTEM STATUS" is "Custom"

Comment: if flashing failes in the middle of progress each time, you already tried with usb 2.0 hub, then guess emmc is weared out. it might possible to boot from sd card, but first dump (encrypted) userdata partition from twrp

Comment: This [is the message](https://imgur.com/a/KsriRGb) where it says fail! Note 5 doesn't have a slot for SD card, could you elaborate, what do you mean by dump userdata?

Comment: **un**tick checkboxes auto-reboot and dangerous settings like repartitioning, flash [twrp-3.4.0-0-noblelte.tar](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3195262) and reboot straight into recovery by keep holding home + vol up + pwr, on PC *'adb pull /dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/USERDATA'* while connected in TWRP recovery

Comment: I've been trying for weeks, the FRP is blocking the process. Previously when I tried heimdall, I don't know how but it removed the FRP. Now it's not working.

Comment: flashing official system should always work regardless of FRP, try real linux (not vm)